# how to include Standard c files in kernel?

Tags: cuda, opencl

Referred by "CUDA Center Of Excellence, IIT Bombay"

I am working on parallelization of a networking tool but I am not able to include standard c files like socket.h in kernel because Kernel does not support standard C header files it only understand some predefined data types and functions. So i just want to know how to include standard header files in kernel or is there any other method for the same?

Comment: If your question is "How to include sockets inside OpenCL kernels" then the answer is "Is impossible, sockets are not visible inside OpenCL kernels". OpenCL kernels can only interact via buffers or static datatypes with host side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just a matter of being unable to include the header.  CUDA and OpenCL kernels run in a specialized software environment, typically on specialized hardware like a GPU, and that software environment does not include a network stack.

CUDA and OpenCL are probably not a good fit for a network application anyway.  They're meant for processor-intensive, [data-parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism) tasks — executing the same algorithm across a large number of data values.  GPUs are designed for executing the same instruction at the same time across many threads, but in a network application, where incoming requests are dispatched to threads, the threads need to be able work independently of each other.  You wouldn't want your application to delay sending one response until 31 other responses are also ready to send.